# How to browse a webserver running in a docker container when the container itself is running in an AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a Django webserver running in a docker container. When the container is running locally, I can see the server running by using a browser to point to the localhost port mapped with the exposed port of the container.

Now I have the same container running in an AWS EC2 instance. The container's exposed port has been mapped to a certain port of the AWS instance. How can I browse the running webserver from local? (I connect to the AWS EC2 using SSH)

Answer (score 1):

First verify the application is the running on EC2 and its responding to localhost, do an ssh and run `curl localhost:PUBLISH_PORT`

If this responding, then run `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4` this will return the public IP address of EC2 instance, open the in browser, for example

54.232.200.77:PUBLISH_PORT

Or you can get the public IP from Ec2 console.
see the public IP arrow.
[image]

Also, Allow the PUBLISH_PORT from the security group.

[image]

[ec2-security-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)